# Updating only changed fields in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

We are using elastic search as a cache Storing data.
There is a job which updates elastic search every 6 hours, which replaces the complete elastic search with the new data.
Now what we want to implement, is that the elastic search data should update only the updated indexes and new added indexes Indexes which have no changes should not be touched.
Is it possible to do this with the elastic search?
Please help here.

Comment: weird! What you mean by replace the complete elastic search with the new data?

Comment: basically flush the old data and add new one.

Comment: just add and don't flush old one

Comment: for update u need to generate the _id by yourself or have the control of it

Comment: Actually I am new to elastic search, So what happens is we have set the flush period dmso every 24hours the data flushes itself. The time that we have set, So increasing the time and just keep on adding to it could be the solution??

Comment: As a caching storage u have to generate id of caching key by yourself right?

Comment: If u don't, i don't have a clue of how u use the caching implementation

Comment: Elasticsearch has no update method the trick is insert a new document with same `_id` key

Comment: @MarcelDjaman True that it doesn't have an update method. In that case what happens when you use setTTL() method.

Answer (score 0):

manage your update changes by insert them into queue ( it can be MySQL table or something ) you must manage your document's ids too.

fetch the data from the queue and use elastic update API with upsert functionality.

```
POST /<indexName>/<type>/<documentID>/_update
{
  "doc" :
      {
         name: "Dennis",
         weight: "70"
      },
  "doc_as_upset" : true
}
```

to update the document or create new documents if the document not exist ( reminds REPLACE in MySQL ).